# Configure Amazon Redirect Rules for 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My plan is to use a single Amazon Bucket to do a 301 redirect from www domains to non-www. domains.

I want to be able to point any URL to it and have it not only performance the redirect on that domain, but also keep the directioy path:

www.site.com/test -> site.com/test

The redirection rules can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

This is what the general setup looks like:

```
RoutingRules> =
    <RoutingRules>
         <RoutingRule>...</RoutingRule>
         [<RoutingRule>...</RoutingRule>   
         ...]
    </RoutingRules>

<RoutingRule> =
   <RoutingRule>
      [ <Condition>...</Condition> ]
      <Redirect>...</Redirect>
   </RoutingRule>

<Condition> =
   <Condition> 
      [ <KeyPrefixEquals>...</KeyPrefixEquals> ]
      [ <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>...</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals> ]
   </Condition>
    Note: <Condition> must has at least one child element.

<Redirect> =
   <Redirect> 
      [ <HostName>...</HostName> ]
      [ <Protocol>...</Protocol> ]
      [ <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>...</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>  ]
      [ <ReplaceKeyWith>...</ReplaceKeyWith> ]
      [ <HttpRedirectCode>...</HttpRedirectCode> ]
   </Redirect>
    Note: <Redirect> must has at least one child element. 
           Also, you can have either ReplaceKeyPrefix with or ReplaceKeyWith, 
           but not both.
```

I would point my www CNAME to this bucket. My question is, given the controls amazon gives us on bucket redirection, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a single bucket and point multiple domains to it. With S3, one custom domain = one unique bucket as the bucket's name must match the custom CNAME you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

@dcro accurately points out that it's strictly one domain name per bucket, because the bucket name has to exactly match the domain name.

If you operate within that constraint, then redirecting every request to the same path at a different host is simple... all you do is choose "Redirect all requests to another hostname" (in the console, as documented on the page you linked to) and that's what S3 does, no rule configuration required.

Every request gets redirected to the exact same path at the specified host, query strings and all.  Actual request from one of my buckets, hostname sanitized but the path /foo/bar was in the actual request, and preserved in the `Location:` header:

```
$ wget --server-response original.example.com/foo/bar -O -
--2013-09-27 17:47:16--  http://original.example.com/foo/bar
Resolving original.example.com (original.example.com)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to original.example.com (original.example.com)|x.x.x.x|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  x-amz-id-2: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  x-amz-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 21:47:18 GMT
  Location: http://target.example.com/foo/bar
  Content-Length: 0
  Server: AmazonS3
```